# Override laravel vendor function (InfyOmLabs/laravel-generator)?

Tags: php, laravel, overriding, vendor

I use this package:
https://github.com/InfyOmLabs/laravel-generator

I would like override a function "**generateScaffoldItems()**" inside
https://github.com/InfyOmLabs/laravel-generator/blob/develop/src/Commands/BaseCommand.php#L104

I copied this function and rewrite in myself module,then regist in Laravel Provider

MyOverrideClass.php

```
public function generateScaffoldItems()
{
    //override...
}
```

MyOverrideProvider.php

```
public function register()
{
    //
    $this->app->booting(function() {
    $loader = AliasLoader::getInstance();
    $loader->alias('InfyOm\Generator\Commands\BaseCommand','App\Overrides\MyOverrideClass');
});
```

But it didn't worked.
Is it possible or maybe exist a better way to override this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alias method is only for classes or services resolved from the IOC. You cannot expect to override a base class in turn overriding all classes that derive from it using anything like this.

The only way is to override all the command classes that you want to eventually override and register the new commands in Kernel.php